# How to get a list from a unicode data in python? Example

Tags: python-2.7, python-unicode

How to get a particular data from Unicode in python?

For example, how I can get the list `[employee1,employee2]` from the below mentioned data?

```
data = u'\\employee\\datavalues         all records \n--------------   --------------------------------------------\ndetails   [employee1,employee2]\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your unicode string is made of fields seperated by spaces, and you're interested in the last field. To extract it:

```
last_field = data.split()[-1]
```

The result should be the unicode string `'[employee1,employee2]'`.

Now, if you want the last field as a list of unicode strings, remove the brackets and split using the comma as separator:

```
list_employees = last_field[1:-1].split(',')
```

You should get: `[u'employee1', u'employee2']`